# How can I "disable" an inline style that is overwriting my CSS?

Tags: css, class, squarespace, inline-styles

I'm writing a Chrome Extension to modify the user interface of Squarespace, which "overlays" CSS on top of your website in order to display the browser-based website builder.

Let's say this is my body CSS:

```
body {
 background-color: #000000;
 background-image: url("/storage/body.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: top center;
}
```

When you open up Squarespace's user interface, it adds a few classes to the CSS with inline styling. So this is added to my code automatically:

```
{
padding-top: 56px;
background-position: 50px 56px;
}
```

So since I'm modifying the user interface with a CSS Chrome Extension I want to essentially "skip" or "disable" those inline styles from being added. I could just use !important on my extension CSS, but some websites might use a different background-position, I don't want to just put "background-position: top center !important;" in my extension. I also don't want to just strip the classes using a script because they're also used for other styling.

Thanks!

Comment: `!important` is the only way to override inline styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely have to keep your inline styles (as in, not moving your styles to an external stylsheet, or at least a `<style>` element in your `<head>`) then use

```
myElement
{
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

This is literally the only CSS way to do it.

You could use Javascript to find the attribute of the element and change it if you wanted, but `!important` is the only thing in CSS that can override inline styles.

:)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/TXmC7/